# React Passing data into propType

Tags: reactjs

First of all i am new with react.js. I uee react starter kit boilerplate. I would like to pass the data of my request inside my propTypes. Is that possible or what am i doing wrong?

Thank you

```
export default class Service extends Component {

static propTypes = {
    services: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.shape({
        id: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
        slug: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
        title: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
        content: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
        titleHover: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
        contentHover: PropTypes.string.isRequired
    })).isRequired,
};
```

This is my function request to graphql

```
async getServices() {
    const resp = await fetch('/graphql', {
        method: 'post',
        headers: {
            Accept: 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            query: '{services{id, slug, title, content, titleHover, contentHover}}',
        }),
        credentials: 'include',
    });
    const { data } = await resp.json();
    if (!data || !data.services) throw new Error('Erreur sur le chargement des services !');

    return data.services;
}
```

i want to get my data inside de componentWillMount and rendering

```
componentDidMount() {

}

componentWillMount() {

    this.props.services = this.getServices();

}

render(){
    return (
        <div className={'root'}>
            <div className={'container'}>
                <h1>Services</h1>
                <ul>
                    {this.props.services.map((item, index) => (
                        <li key={index} >
                            <h1>{item.title}</h1>
                            <span

                                dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: item.content }} />
                        </li>
                    ))}
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
}
```

Comment: Check this out: https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/initial-ajax.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Component can't set it's properties by itself, you should manage your services in a **state** instead:

```
componentWillMount() {
    this.setState({
        services: await this.getServices()
    })
}
```

and in **render** function (notice this.**state**.services):

```
<ul>
    {this.state.services.map((item, index) => (
        <li key={index} >
            <h1>{item.title}</h1>
            <span

                dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: item.content }} />
        </li>
    ))}
</ul>
```

More informations about state in [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html#reactive-state)

***edit***

Also, you could use **this.setState** inside getServices function like so

```
...
if (!data || !data.services) throw new Error('Erreur sur le chargement des services !');

this.setState({
    services: data.services
})
```

then you can just call **this.getServices()** whenever you want to fetch services from your API, for example in **componentWillMount** function:

```
componentWillMount() {
    this.getServices()
}
```